# How to add html5 data attribute to Html.TextBox in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

The `Html.TextBox` syntax is:

```
public static MvcHtmlString TextBox(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, string name, 
       object value, object htmlAttributes);
```

So, i put my data attribute in `htmlAttributes`. I have tried

```
@Html.TextBox("date",Model.Date,new { data-myid="aaa"})
```

but that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Try using underscore `_` character.

```
@Html.TextBox("date",Model.Date,new { data_myid="aaa"})
```

The runtime will convert that to `data-myid`

Comment: +1 Even if you add `data_my_id_attribute` it will convert the whole to `data-my-id-attribute`!

Answer (score 1):

For a friendlier syntax, you could try: http://buildmvc.codeplex.com/

```
@Html.BuildTextBox("date", Model.Date).Data("myid", "aaa")
```